# elasticsearch not analyzed still tokenize string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which contains 4 entries.

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "da_6",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
    "message" : "hello world"
}
    }, {
      "_index" : "da_6",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
    "message" : "hello worldetc"
}
    }, {
      "_index" : "da_6",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "4",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
    "message" : "etc hello world"
}
    }, {
      "_index" : "da_6",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "3",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
    "message" : "hello etc world"
}
    } ]
```

I have set the mapping to "string" / "not_analyzed" when I created the index and I am sure it has been applied.

The Mappings:

```
"da_6" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
          "message" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When a user types "hello w", I want it to show the 1st one first, then the 2nd one and the 3rd one. Since the  4th one doesn't contain "hello w" as a whole string, it's not supposed to show in the result.

I've tried `query_string`, search for "hello w*", but it shows all 4 results (seems like still tokenize the content.

Is there a search method behaves like `IndexOf (js)` which gives result that only contains the given query string ("hello w" in this case)?

Comment: Where's the fourth entry?

Comment: The problem with your query could be that you do not provide a default field. Than the _all field is used. If you provide the default field as message you will get other results. I do not have an answer (yet) to your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the match_phrase_prefix query, I could return the three items you wanted. I did use another mapping. I use the standard analyzer (so no index: not_analyzed):

```
GET /da_6/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": "hello w"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Jettro, thanks for your answer. Actually, I was using "match_phrase_prefix" before. However, when it comes to more data, elasticsearch seems to stop the query after it reaches the max_expansion so that it can improve the performance. In that case, it may miss some correct results

Comment: Based on your question I could not understand how big the text became.